# Android 11+ Java - Picking a PDF file from Downloads folder without opening an Activity

Tags: java, android, pdf

Before Android 11, I could ask for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and when I called:

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".pdf"));
```

then I got the list of PDF files in the Downloads folder.

But starting with Android 11, to do the same, I need the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, with Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION turned on.

But I don't need write permission at all, this approach includes way too much! No wonder they are inspecting apps that use this permission closely.

The only way I can access PDF files is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setType("application/pdf").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

(Or the newer ActivityResultContracts way.)

But my problem with these is that they open an Activity that I have zero control of. I would like a deeper integration. If I cannot get just a list of Files, then at least a picker that can be displayed inside Fragment.

I did a very thorough search, but I have found no solution. Please help!

Comment: You could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and ask the user for permission one time to a tree of their choice. You can then use `DocumentFile` to (slowly) identify the PDF content in that tree. However, not all users will want to grant you that broad of access; you should still offer `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or the older `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) approach.

Comment: This sounded like a nice idea. Sadly however, the Downloads folder cannot be selected for security reasons. Additionally, I don't really need access to entire folders. I'm open to using the system's ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT stuff, but I would like it to open inside a Fragment then. All this is about is integration.

Comment: "Additionally, I don't really need access to entire folders" -- you were trying to access all of external storage. "I would like it to open inside a Fragment then" -- other than activity embedding on newer versions of Android, there is no option for this. And I don't know if that UI is embeddable that way.

Comment: `I would like it to open inside a Fragment ` Have no idea what you mean. How would that look like then?

Comment: I just wonder if there is a way to let the system lead the user in choosing a file, while not switching to another Activity, but integrate that view inside the application.

Comment: Actually, I cannot believe there is no way to simply ask for read access to the Downloads folder for files other than pictures and videos, only to ask for a read-write access to the entire system (with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), which is only given to file manager apps actually.